# Swift Remove 1 node moving after collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have nodes falling from the top of the screen every second or so. 
When the player (at the bottom of the screen) collides with a falling node I want that particular node to be removed from the screen but have the other continue to fall.

I thought calling node.removeFromParent() might do this or might remove all of the nodes but nothing is happening regardless.

Here is what I have:

Making the nodes fall:

```
func makeMete() {

    let meteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "mete.png")
    let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.width)
    let meteOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - self.frame.width / 2
    let moveMete = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -2 * self.frame.height), duration: TimeInterval(self.frame.height / 300))

    let mete = SKSpriteNode(texture: meteTexture)
    mete.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + meteOffset, y: self.frame.midY + self.frame.height / 2)

    mete.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: meteTexture.size().height / 2)
    mete.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    mete.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
    mete.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
    mete.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue

    mete.run(moveMete)
    self.addChild(mete)




}
```

Detecting contact:

```
 func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue {



    player.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    isUserInteractionEnabled = false

   mete.removeFromParent()


    }
```

.removeFromParent() seems to only work for me when there is one node on screen. Any more then it doesn't work.

Comment: The variable `mete` will always refer to the last mete created, not the one involved in the collision. So the `removeFromParent` will be working, it'll just be removing some other node that you may not have noticed.

Comment: You might find your code clearer if you cal the mete's physics category `ColliderType.mete`. Also, are you sure that the `contactTest` and `collision` bit masks should be the same as the `category`? What is the category of the player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use mete it references the actual object mete and I assume there are many metes on screen. Try referencing the actual node from the physics body and removing that from the parent.

Replace

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue {

player.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
isUserInteractionEnabled = false
mete.removeFromParent()

}
```

With

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue  {

        contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()

}else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue {
        contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
    }
```

The .node gives you access to the actual instance in question.

Good Luck!

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly thanks!! I've just posted another little question if you wouldn't mind taking a look!

Comment: False alarm I can't post for another 30minutes or so. I'm trying to get a function that moves my background to stop upon collision. bg.run(moveBGForever). I've tried .removeAllActions but this doesn't do it.